# AOP/PostSharp and dirty-checking - getting property name the better way?

Tags: postsharp

My aspect:

```
  [Serializable]
        [MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Class, Inheritance = MulticastInheritance.Strict)]
        public sealed class NotifyPropertyChangedAttribute : InstanceLevelAspect
        {
             [OnLocationSetValueAdvice, MulticastPointcut(Targets = MulticastTargets.Property)]
            public void OnPropertySet(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
            {
                if (args.Value == args.GetCurrentValue()) return;
                args.ProceedSetValue();

                IPersistent iENtity = this.Instance as IPersistent;
                if (iENtity != null)
                {
                    // do something with iENtity
                    // need to identify property name without using reflection
                }
           }
        }
```

I have applied this NotifyPropertyChangedAttribute to entire class so I can process property changes, everything works as expected.

But I would like to know the name of the property which was changed (so I can store the names of dirty properties in some collection). I wanted to use LocationInterceptionArgs::Location but I read this:

```
"Using this property causes the aspect weaver to generate code that has non-trivial runtime overhead."
```

Is there any other way how I can get the name of affected property in my aspect but without using reflection or other code which has big runtime overhead?

Any ideas (or better - examples)? Maybe I can implement it some other way? I just need some way to identify the property at runtime, even without a name - just some value which I can use to find the property in some Dictionary<> later...

Thanks.